# Making a site more mobile friendly

Tags: html, css

Trying to make my site more mobile friendly and can't understand the help offered here. I have the following setup, a basic Index page and a stylesheet css page. I have div elements and < p > elements that are set for all the text on my site.

```
p {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    left: 150px;
    position: relative;

}
```

Is my < p > element, to push it off the left side when viewing on desktop. All the text on my site is in between < p > tags, i also use  tags to the same effect. I am trying to make my page better for mobile viewing, and have added the  to my code but would like to customize it a little better.

What would be a way i could make it so when viewing from a mobile device, it doesn't have the left: 150px; attribute, so it fills the screen better? The only other factor i have is

```
div {  
  width: 1000px;   
  border: 0px solid black;  
}  
div.a {  
  word-wrap: normal;  
}  
div.b {  
  word-wrap: break-word;

}
```

Which i use to wrap the text to fit screen when i have a paragraph or two written.

Comment: Have you read anything about css media queries?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and delete the `left: 150px;` and add `text-align: center`. it will affect the desktop and the mobile view.

OR you can add this media query:

```
@media screen AND (max-width: 767px) {
p { 
   text-align: center !important; 
 }
}
```

you can change the value of the max-width `(max-width: 767px)` and make any breakpoint you like. just change the css rules for the mobile view and add them inside the media query.

Comment: Okay i see that, are you saying i need to add the @media part into my css stylesheet ? Or looking at that, i need to encapsulate the ' p { ' part to include @media? And if i did that and changed it to text-align centre, would that centre on desktop and phone? Thank you for helping me out too.

Comment: You can copy and paste all the media query code. starting from "@" and all the way down to the last "}". This will make all the paragraphs to be centered. starting from the smallest screen width (around 320px) up to the max-width value noted in the media query (767px). For screens with resolution higher than 767px, all the p elements will use the other css rules you have for this elements(p).